# What does the phrase "fire a long line" mean here?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from an action game:

> You need to grapple downward, then fire a long line through a gap.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase **fire a long line**. The preceding sentence describes the importance of momentum in moving across tight passages.

The player has to swing herself to the top of the mountain avoiding different obstacles including collapsing rocks, snowbanks, etc.

Comment: Is the "line" something like a rope or cable?

Comment: @Cascabel There is no mention of a rope or cable. The player uses grappling hooks to scale a mountain.

Comment: Grappling hooks are usually attached to a rope. Otherwise what good are they?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grappling_hook Also I question the use of "grapple" as a verb to describe going down a mountain.

Comment: A line is another name for a rope. It sounds like the character should have some method (gun, rocket) of projecting a line at a distant object (the gap). I was thinking something like the method used between ships at sea where a gun is used to shoot a projectile attached to a light line across to another ship. This can then be used to pull across a heavier rope (for a bosun's chair or a tow) or a pipe for ship-to-ship refueling.

Comment: When I was searching for powered grappling irons, I saw a crossbow version pictured; perhaps that was what the author had in mind for **fire a long line.**

Comment: @PeterJennings The player has a grappling gun.

Answer (score 2):

To get a long line to the top of a cliff you need a rocket propelled grappling iron/ grappling hook. These exist in real life:
[image]

and as props for film and cosplay:
[image: grapple and line moviegunguy.com]

Comment: I am not sure if this question will stay (no research) but this is a good answer.